# Stop Exception from async lambda propagating up call stack

Tags: c#, exception, async-await

The code below has a TaskMonitor class, which is a modified version of Stephen Cleary's [NotifyTask class](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/master/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs).  The Worker class uses the TaskMonitor class to run Worker.CheckStatus asynchronously.

Worker.CheckStatus can often throw an Exception (e.g. database connection issues).  I'd like TaskMonitor.Monitor to stop that Exception from reaching Program.Main and expose it via the Exception and InnerException properties.  The catch block in TaskMonitor.Monitor gets hit but doesn't swallow the Exception as expected; the Exception gets passed up to Program.Main and crashes the app.  How can I stop the Exception in TaskMonitor.Monitor?

```
public sealed class TaskMonitor {
    // Based on Stephen Cleary's NotifyTaskCompletion:
    // https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/master/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs

    public TaskMonitor(Task task = null) {
        Task = task;
    }

    public AggregateException Exception {
        get {
            return Task?.Exception;
        }
    }

    public Exception InnerException {
        get {
            return Exception?.InnerException;
        }
    }

    public bool IsCompleted {
        get {
            return Task != null && Task.IsCompleted;
        }
    }

    public bool IsRunning {
        get {
            return Task != null && !Task.IsCompleted;
        }
    }

    private async Task Monitor(Task task) {
        try {
            if(task != null) {
                await task;
            }
        }
        catch {
            // Drop exceptions
        }
        finally {
            // do other stuff here like raise PropertyChanged
        }
    }

    private Task _task;

    public Task Task {
        get => _task;
        set {
            if(Task != value) {
                _task = value;
                _ = Monitor(Task);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Worker {
    public Worker() {
        CheckStatusMonitor = new TaskMonitor();
    }

    public void CheckStatus() {
        if(!CheckStatusMonitor.IsRunning) {
            CheckStatusMonitor.Task = Task.Run(async () => {
                var newStatus = WorkerStatus.Unknown;
                try {
                    // Force a database connection failure
                    var cn = new SqlConnection();
                    await cn.OpenAsync();

                    newStatus = WorkerStatus.Good;
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    newStatus = WorkerStatus.Error;
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally {
                    Status = newStatus;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public TaskMonitor CheckStatusMonitor { get; private set; }

    public WorkerStatus Status { get; private set; }
}

public enum WorkerStatus {
    Unknown,
    Error,
    Good,
}

class Program {
    public static async Task Main() {
        var worker = new Worker();
        worker.CheckStatus();
        await worker.CheckStatusMonitor.Task;
        Debug.WriteLine(worker.CheckStatusMonitor.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: You set `_task` to the `Task` returned from `Task.Run`, not the `Task` returned from `Monitor`. You then await that in `await worker.CheckStatusMonitor.Task;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The catch block in TaskMonitor.Monitor gets hit but doesn't swallow the Exception as expected; the Exception gets passed up to Program.Main and crashes the app. How can I stop the Exception in TaskMonitor.Monitor?

In `Main`, your code is doing `await worker.CheckStatusMonitor.Task;` The task returned from `TaskMonitor.Task` is the `Task.Run` task from `Worker.CheckStatus`, not the task returned from `TaskMonitor.Monitor`.

If you want to ignore exceptions, then you'll need to `await` the correct task:

```
public Task Task {
  get => _task;
  set {
    _task = Monitor(value);
  }
}
```

Note that the `if(Task != value)` was removed, since that clearly won't work because the task is being replaced.

Comment: I was so certain that the Task.Run call in CheckStatus was somehow running as an async void that I missed that the code was awaiting the wrong Task.  To fix this I added a TaskMonitor.MonitorTask property (like NotifyTask.TaskCompleted) and modified the other TaskMonitor properties to reference the appropriate Task.  Thanks for your help!